# SharePoint like functionality for Office Documents

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ms-office, office-2010

We have a document library that is built inhouse. We are migrating to SharePoint 2010 Document Library, but this will be a time consuming process and many very old documents may not get moved to SharePoint at all. I would like to provide the same experience for our users when they open a document from SharePoint or our legacy system. The behavior I would like is like when you open a Workbook or Document that is rendered in the browser using the "Open In Excel" and "Open in Word" button that you get when you open a document stored in a Share Point Document Library.

I am not sure what this technology is called or where to start looking to configure this or integrate into an addin.

Any starting points are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear on what your question is, but perhaps you are looking to use the Office Web Apps. This allows you to use the Office applications within the browser.

Comment: Thanks Doug. That is something I've looked into. I don't want to use Office in a browser. What I am after is when I open the workbook from my application, i want it to load up in Excel. That part I've done.

Comment: To clarify, when you open a document SharePoint, it loads the document in a browser. You get a button that allows you to open the document in Word / Excel, whichever is appropriate. When you click this button you are asked (dialog box) if you want to open the document for edit or read-only. When you open Read-Only you get a banner just below the ribbon that indicates the document is read only. It also provides a button to allow editing. That is the behavior I am after.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for then is to change the default behavior from opening in the browser to opening in the client application (Office). There is a list setting to do this. Go to List Settings -> Advanced. Change the "Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents" setting to "Open in the client application". Sorry I didn't see your response sooner, and I hope this helps.